# How to set zoom controls on TextView and ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, pinchzoom, zooming

i want to set zoom controls on TextView and ImageView. where, when zoom in pressed then all the textview and imageview  are being zoomed in, and when zoom out pressed all the textview and imageview are being zoomed out with the function of scrollable left & right.
or, is it possible pinch to zoom only in imageview?
my try is below, but not worked perfectly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="sample.app"/>


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical"/>

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:text="something in text view"
android:textColor="#ff0000"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:text="another textview"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:text="Parts list"
android:textColor="#ff0000"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:src="@drawable/melody" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<ZoomControls
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/zoomControls"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

```js
public class melodygenerator extends AppCompatActivity {
ZoomControls zoomit;
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.melodygenerator);

        zoomit = (ZoomControls)findViewById(R.id.zoomControls);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        
        zoomit.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View V){
                float x = imageView.getScaleX();
                float y = imageView.getScrollY();
                
                imageView.setScaleX ((int) (x+1));
                imageView.setScaleY((int) (y+1));
        }
    });
        zoomit.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View V) {
                float x = imageView.getScaleX();
                float y = imageView.getScrollY();

                imageView.setScaleX ((int) (x-1));
                imageView.setScaleY((int) (y-1));
                
            }
        });
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code.

```
public class melodygenerator extends AppCompatActivity {
    ZoomControls zoomit;
    ImageView imageView;
    boolean isZoomeed;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.melodygenerator);

        zoomit = (ZoomControls)findViewById(R.id.zoomControls);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        zoomit.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View V){
                float x = imageView.getScaleX();
                float y = imageView.getScrollY();

                if(isZoomeed) {
                    isZoomeed = false;
                    imageView.setScaleX ((int) (x-1));
                    imageView.setScaleY((int) (y-1));
                }else {
                    isZoomeed = true;
                    imageView.setScaleX ((int) (x+1));
                    imageView.setScaleY((int) (y+1));
                }

            }
        });

    }}
```